# Ubuntu live USB install does not detect SSD

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb, ssd, detect

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with a 500GB SSD (no other drives). Windows 10 is installed, and I have shrunk the Windows partition to leave 450 GB unallocated. In BIOS the SATA disk is detected, UEFI is on, Secure Boot is off, and RAID is disabled (SATA mode on).
When I boot from an Ubuntu 22.04 USB stick, the SSD is not detected.
Does anyone have a suggestion please?

I have included the output from `lsblk -a`and from `fdisk -l` .

Results of `lsblk -a` :

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0   2.1G  1 loop /rofs 
loop1    7:1    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587 
loop2    7:2    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5 
loop3    7:3    0 163.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1635 
loop4    7:4    0 400.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112 
loop5    7:5    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535 
loop6    7:6    0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/582 
loop7    7:7    0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14 
loop8    7:8    0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292 
loop9    7:9    0     0B  0 loop 
sda      8:0    1   7.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    1   3.6G  0 part /cdrom 
├─sda2   8:2    1   4.1M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    1   300K  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    1     4G  0 part /var/crash/var/log
```

Results of `fdisk -l` :

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.13 GiB, 2288189440 bytes, 4469120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 61.96 MiB, 64970752 bytes, 126896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 163.29 MiB, 171225088 bytes, 334424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 400.8 MiB, 420265984 bytes, 820832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 45.86 MiB, 48091136 bytes, 93928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 284 KiB, 290816 bytes, 568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 7.61 GiB, 8166703104 bytes, 15950592 sectors
Disk model: USB DISK        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9240A165-D190-4AB6-8A10-46DC207B42EE

Device       Start      End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       64  7465119 7465056  3.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  7465120  7473615    8496  4.1M EFI System
/dev/sda3  7473616  7474215     600  300K Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  7475200 15950528 8475329    4G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/loop8: 46.96 MiB, 49242112 bytes, 96176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Change 'SATA Mode' to 'ACPI Mode' in UEFI ( what some people still incorrectly call BIOS ) and try again. Please report back. If that doesn't work tell us how you made the installation medium by detail ( program used and settings ).

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware to latest available. What model Dell? My Dell 5310 with Intel 11 Gen Intel chip worked with UEFI Secure boot and RAID mode on. ( forgot to change & was surprised it worked).  I installed Kubuntu 22.04.1. I did have to turn off Windows fast start up & bitlocker. Windows had updated firmware, so that was current.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The SSD is shown in Windows as  "WD UEFI PC SN520 NVMe 512GB".  UEFI/BIOS setup shows "Port Enablement M.2 PCIeSSD-0/SATA-2" is ON, which I take to mean that the drive is enabled. The setting "SATA Operation" is "AHCI Mode" (there's no "ACPI" mode offered). I have updated my BIOS from Windows, &  "WD Dashboard" tells me I have the latest driver for my SSD. My installation medium  is an 8GB USB drive made with the "Startup Disk Creator" on my desktop PC (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS). Default settings. The SSD is still invisible in Ubuntu!

Comment: Ping? My problem remains, does anyone have a suggestion please?